# Download Visual Studio 2012 RC from MSDNAA and update to final version in september?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dreamspark

If i download Visual Studio 2012 RC from MSDNAA (dreamspark) today, will it just be a upgrade later or will I have to reinstall everything when it's released in September?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which edition (Ultimate/Premium/Professional) you'll be getting, just get the [90 day evaluation version of the **release version**](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads) for now, and enter your actual key in September.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But is this the final version and not the RC? It sounds strange to me that the trial version of a program is released before the actual program itself.

Comment: @HerrNilsson As strange as it may be, yes, [that is the release version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-rtw.aspx).